# React Native reset some property of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a long initial state and I want to reset some of my states `onPress` of a button.

Let's have an example of `this.state`:

```
this.state = {
  A: "",
  B: 0,
  C: [
    {
      x: 0,
      y: "Palette",
      z: true,
    }
  ],
  tempA: "",
  tempB: 0,
  tempC: [
    {
      x: 0,
      y: "Palette",
      z: true,
    }
  ]
};
```

And I want to reset those started with `temp`. So I created:

```
const initialState = {
  tempA: "",
  tempB: 0,
  tempC: [
    {
      x: 0,
      y: "Palette",
      z: true,
    }
  ]
};
```

but I don't know how can i `setState` to set `this.state.A` and reset `initialState`! I've tried to use:

```
setState({ A: 10, initialState })
// OR
setState([{ A: 10}, initialState ])
```

But no result!

Any idea?

> Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with object spreading:

```
setState({ ...initialState, A: 10 })
```

Also `A: 10` should be defined after spreading to let it override the `initialState` properties.

Comment: In his example above A is not a part of initialState, so order does not matter
setState({ A: 10, ...initialState }) will work same way